# mounting nfs volume errors out

Tags: docker, nfs, openmediavault

From my docker host terminal, I am trying to mount an nfs shared folder of a raspberry pi installed with OpenMediaVault.  The below command fails with message - "mount.nfs: mounting 192.168.142.123:/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory".

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 192.168.142.123:/export/myapp /var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp/_data
```

In Pi, in OMV, I have checked and ensured that a shared folder is created and in OMV --> Services --> NFS --> Shares, I see it as myapp [on dev/sda1, export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/]  with due permissions for NFS client IPs.  Again, the /etc/exports file has the entry

```
/export/mysqldb 192.168.142.0/24(fsid=<some ID>,rw,subtree_check,insecure)
```

Also, the output of the lsblk -f shows -->

```
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda                                                                                 
└─sda1      ext4   1.0          <some UUID>                          400.4G     0% /export/myapp
```

I just tried doing a file copy from docker host to nfs host which worked just fine...

```
scp test.txt 192.168.142.123:/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/
```

Where am I going wrong with the docker mount ?  Help much appreciated...

Comment: This has been on-topic [for years](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+lsblk+mount)

Answer (score 0):

The path `/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/` is the actual shared folder on your Raspberry Pi that you have set up in [OpenMediaVault (OMV)](https://www.openmediavault.org/). That is the directory that you are sharing over the network via NFS.
The path `/export/myapp` mentioned in your `lsblk -f` output seems to be a local directory on your Raspberry Pi. It is not clear if this is the same as /export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/ or a different directory.

Check that the NFS export path in `/etc/exports` matches the actual directory structure of your shared folder. In your case, it should be `/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/` ('`/export/...`'not "`export/...`" as in OMV --> Services --> NFS --> Shares, `myapp [on dev/sda1, export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/]`).

Modify the `/etc/exports` file on the Raspberry Pi to correctly point to the shared folder. The entry should be like:

```
/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp/ 192.168.142.0/24(fsid=<some ID>,rw,subtree_check,insecure)
```

Make sure the mount command on your Docker host matches the exported path. Based on your description, the correct mount command would be:

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 192.168.142.123:/export/nfs/docker/volume/myapp /var/lib/docker/volumes/myapp/_data
```

You should get:

```bash
 Docker Host                          Raspberry Pi (OpenMediaVault)
+-------------------+               +---------------------------------+
|                   |               |                                 |
|   /var/lib/docker |               |   /export/nfs/docker/volume     |
|   /volumes/myapp  |  NFS Mount    |   /myapp                        |
|   /_data          | <------------>|   (Shared Folder)               |
|                   |               |                                 |
+-------------------+               +---------------------------------+
```